# A cookie code that make the following

Tags: javascript, cookies, redirect, if-statement

First, I would like to have an easy code that creates a cookie called "x" for example and another code to put in other html that creates a cookie called "y". Then, in another html file, some code that checks if there is a previous cookie and:

- If there is a previous cookie called "x", redirect to for example x.com page.
- If there is a previous cookie called "y",  redirect to other page, for example y.com.
- If there isn't a previous cookie, do nothing.

The final code is:
create the cookie username en:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cookieDate = new Date(2012, 5, 02)
  document.cookie = "username=en;expires=" + cookieDate.toGMTString();
</script>
```

create the cookie username es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var cookieDate = new Date(2012, 5, 02)
      document.cookie = "username=es;expires=" + cookieDate.toGMTString();
    </script>
```

Read the cookie and go to x.com if it's with the cookie has the value en and go to y if has the value es (and do nothing if there isn't cookie):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_cookie (username)
  {
    var results = document.cookie.match(username + '=(.*?)(;|$)');

    if (results[1] == "en")
      location.replace("http://x.com");
    if (results[1] == "es")
      location.replace("http://y.com");    
    else
      return null;
  }

  get_cookie('username');
</script>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to write some code? Please provide that code so that people can at least debug it for you.
Don't expect to see a complete code written for you in this website. People here are so strict in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code defines a redirect function, but i don't see where you call the redirect function.

setting the cookie should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cookieDate = new Date(2012, 5, 02)
  document.cookie = "username=en;expires=" + cookieDate.toGMTString();
</script>
```

Retrieve the cookie values like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_cookie (username)
  {
    var results = document.cookie.match(username + '=(.*?)(;|$)');

    if (results[1] == "en")
      location.replace("http://x.com");
    if (results[1] == "es")
      location.replace("http://y.com");    
    else
      return null;
  }

  get_cookie('username');
</script>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work too. I think that var results should define the value of the cookie "username", because it's that i need. Then if the value of the cookie username is "en" to redirect. I think the last part is okay. How can i put in var results the value ok cookie?                                                              
thanks

Comment: And other thing: is it okay the first part of my code? this: 
<script type="text/javascript">
document.cookie = "username=en;
                  expires=15/02/2012 00:00:00";
</script>

With this code i only want to create a cookie with the name username and with the value en, is it okay?
Thanks

Comment: thanks for continue helping but i can't make it go well. I uploaded to a web. You can check if there is some fail: www.pruebasroy.webcindario.com   
I enter www.pruebasroy.webcindario.com/en.html    and then in the index (www.pruebasroy.webcindario.com/index.html) and the page doesn't redirect me.

Comment: you need to call `get_cookie('username')` somewhere. i've updated my code to call it.

Comment: I took a look at your site, looks like the cookie isn't being set, probably because I left in a '\' that caused an error. I removed it, please update your code.

Comment: Yes, i forget to call the function, and I copy the "extra bar" hahaha. Now it's perfect and goes well. I will update the codes in the web too if someone wants to see it. I also edit the post with your code. Thank you very much Yisroel.